# What is the cygwin equivalent of the mac command "cd ~/Documents"?

Tags: cygwin

I saw this command on a tutorial and I'm not sure what the Cygwin analogue is. Any support is greatly apprecated.

Answer (score 0):

as `~` means the Cygwin home directory and probably you want the Windows Home Directory that it can be different, so try

```
cd /cygdrive/c/users/your_windows_user_name/Documents
```

If instead you want really the Cygwin Home Directory than the command is the same

```
cd ~/Documents
```